# Is this discrete optimization problem NP-complete?

Tags: convex-optimization, discrete-optimization, np-complete

Consider a finite set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}$.
Minimize
$$\sum_n \left( \max_{(n',i,a) \in A, n=n'} (a + x_i) + \max_{(n',i,a) \in A, n=n'} (-a - x_i) \right)$$
over $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, where $m$ is large enough.

This problem is convex since the formula is sum of maximum of convex (or affine) functions. Thus a local minimum is a global minimum. It seems there might be an iterative greedy algorithm that minimizes the goal little by little and eventually reaches a local minimum in polynomially many steps.

If you are uncomfortable with its formulation with $\mathbb{R}$, just replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$. Does it change anything? I am not sure, but probably not.

The decision version of this problem would ask "is the minimum less than or equal to a given
$k$?". It is NP since $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ would work as a polynomial length certificate.

My question: Is it NP-complete? Is it a known problem?

Thank you very much in advance. My expectation is that it is a known problem. It looks like a famous problem. I just don't know the name of the problem. It would simply answer my question if you leave me a proper search keyword so that I could search it on the internet.

Comment: $a + x_i$ is a convex function, so is $-a - x_i$. It is known that maximum of convex functions is again convex, and that sum of convex functions is again convex.

Comment: So your concern is that the convexity condition is meaningless if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{N}$. That's a very valid concern. In that case, we may use $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm not sure how much that will change the problem. Properties of convexity is still applicable when the domain is descrete.

Comment: I would very much appreciate answers that will point out some degeneracy caused by my ambiguity in formulating the problem.

Comment: Isn't $\max -f = -\min f$?

Comment: Yes? We could use that to restate the problem. Anyway, they are the same problem.

Comment: It would be the same function, however

Comment: Where is $n$ inside the sum?

Comment: I don't see your point "it would be the same function".

Comment: $n$ appears in $(n,i,a) \in A$. They are meant to be the same $n$. I think this would make a succint notation, but may be not a standard one?

Comment: Does $a+x_i$ depend on $n$?

Comment: $\max - \min$ is more interesting, I would say

Comment: $\max-\min$ would be a more natural formulation, and that's also the original forumation I thought of. I just wanted to make it clear that it is convex.

Comment: $a+x_i$ depends on $n$. Is there any reason why not?